# Can I specify the user who is creating a release?

Tags: octopus-deploy

When using create-release can I specify the user who is creating the release independent of the user I'm using to execute `octo.exe`?

The scenario in mind is our build server will begin a build based on a push (and it knows who made the commit), but as far as Octopus Deploy is concerned the build server created the release, and not the person who committed.

Answer (score 1):

We use an Octopus Service Account with an API Key, and we call it `build-deploy-bot`. This is the account that TeamCity uses to create the release in Octo.exe.

When the release is created, we also include Release Notes with links to all commits, as well as the build overview. In doing this, we can see what commits made it into the specific release.

Since a "person" didn't create the release, we don't associate the release with a person.

For reference, here's the script we use to generate releases in Teamcity.
https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/716ffd1e4213ecfc8a8b